# How do I have multiple functions available to run via PHP using multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, function

I managed to get my previous project working where I click a button on a webpage and it makes some text change on the webpage for all the devices that are viewing it, by making the button click run PHP code which tells all devices to run a JavaScript function, which reads the value of a text file that the PHP code is changing.

Now I want to do the same thing, but I want to have *3* different buttons that are running *3* different JavaScript functions on all the devices viewing the webpage.

I have tried making 3 different PHP files, and 3 different text files, and 3 different functions, but it didn't work (it seemed to think I was clicking the buttons when I wasn't), and also seemed like not a very efficient way to do it. I think it was to do with having multiple $.get() functions running at once, for all the different functions.

How would I have 1 PHP file, and 1 $.get() function and make this work?

Thanks,
Fjpackard.

Edit:
Here is the code I tried, although I would like it if I could do it a different and more efficient way if possible.

**index.html:**

```
<title>PHP Test</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>

    var theButton;

    function myClick()
    {
        $.post('script.php', {});
    }

    function myClick2()
    {
        $.post('script2.php', {});
    }

    function myClick3()
    {
        $.post('script3.php', {});
    }

    function myFunc() {
        //The code you want to run on the clients
        $("#theDiv").text("Say Hello");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#theDiv").text("");
        },2000);
    }

    function myFunc2() {
        //The code you want to run on the clients
        $("#theDiv").text("Say Goodbye");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#theDiv").text("");
        },2000);
    }

    function myFunc3() {
        //The code you want to run on the clients
        $("#theDiv").text("Zip Your Mouth");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#theDiv").text("");
        },2000);
    }

    var lastValue = '';
    var lastValue2 = '';
    var lastValue3 = '';

        $("document").ready(function() {
        var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/);
        if (agentID) {

            // mobile code here
            $("#btn1").remove();
            $("#btn2").remove();
            $("#btn3").remove();
            setInterval(function() {
                $.get(
                    'script.php',
                    {},
                    function (data) {
                        if (data != lastValue) {
                            myFunc();
                            lastValue = data;
                        }
                    }

                );
                /*$.get(
                    'script2.php',
                    {},
                    function (data2) {
                        if (data2 != lastValue2) {
                            myFunc2();
                            lastValue = data2;
                        }
                    }

                );
                $.get(
                    'script3.php',
                    {},
                    function (data3) {
                        if (data3 != lastValue3) {
                            myFunc3();
                            lastValue = data3;
                        }
                    }

                );*/
            },100);

        }
        else {
            $("#theDiv").remove();
        }


    });

</script>
<div id="theDiv"></div>
<button id="btn1" class="btn" onclick="myClick()">Say Hello</button><br>
<button id="btn2" class="btn" onclick="myClick2()">Say Goodbye</button><br>
<button id="btn3" class="btn" onclick="myClick3()">Zip Your Mouth</button>
```

**script.php:**

```
<?php
    // Disable cache
    header("Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT");
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    $file = 'file.txt';

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
    {
        // POST request

        $previous = file_get_contents($file);
        if ($previous === 'true')
        {
            file_put_contents($file, 'false');
        }
        else
        {
            file_put_contents($file, 'true');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // not POST request, we assume it's GET

        echo file_get_contents($file);
    }
    exit();
?>
```

**script2.php:**

```
<?php
    // Disable cache
    header("Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT");
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    $file = 'file2.txt';

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
    {
        // POST request

        $previous = file_get_contents($file);
        if ($previous === 'true')
        {
            file_put_contents($file, 'false');
        }
        else
        {
            file_put_contents($file, 'true');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // not POST request, we assume it's GET

        echo file_get_contents($file);
    }
    exit();
?>
```

**script3.php:**

```
<?php
    // Disable cache
    header("Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT");
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    $file = 'file3.txt';

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
    {
        // POST request

        $previous = file_get_contents($file);
        if ($previous === 'true')
        {
            file_put_contents($file, 'false');
        }
        else
        {
            file_put_contents($file, 'true');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // not POST request, we assume it's GET

        echo file_get_contents($file);
    }
    exit();
?>
```

Comment: Please show us the code you tried to use to make this work, or at least get as far as you can... then we can help fill in the missing part.

Comment: Make the three buttons make three ajax calls to the three php functions

Comment: I think I already am... I would like it to be one PHP function if possible that will do different things depending on which button I clicked.

Comment: need to learn to start using arguments of functions. Instead of calling same scipt many times renaming function, write it once and pass arguments to it instead

Comment: OK, I'll try that now and tell you if I have any luck.

Comment: OK, I've just got the one PHP script now (script.php), and I'm using '$.post("script.php?button=1/2/3", {});', but I don't know what to do for the '$.get()' function! Any code samples...? I'm kind of a newbie when it comes to back-end stuff :P

Comment: In your php script, do this: `print($_GET['button']);` and then use the DOM inspector in the browser to see the output of the ajax call. That's how you read get in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some `GET` parameters and an `array` in the php file:

JS code:

```
function myClick()
    {
        $.post('script.php?button=1', {});
    }

    function myClick2()
    {
        $.post('script.php?button=2', {});
    }

    function myClick3()
    {
        $.post('script.php?button=3', {});
    }
```

And then in `script.php`:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // Disable cache
    header("Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT");
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    $fileArray = array("1" => "file.txt", "2" => 'file2.txt', "3" => 'file3.txt');

    if(isset($_SESSION['lastFile']) && !isset($_GET['button'])){
        $file = $_SESSION['lastFile'];
    }else if(isset($_GET['button'])){
        $file = $fileArray[$_GET['button']];
    }else{
        $file = "file.txt";
    }

    $_SESSION['lastFile'] = $file;
```

This way, if no `GET` parameter is set, the script will fall back on an previous used file ( set in the session ), or else load the default ( file.txt )

So if you do the Ajax request to `script.php?button=2`, file `file2.txt` will be loaded, and inserted into the `session variable`.

Later when you request `script.php` ( without the button part ), the script detects that there isn't any `button get variable`. But it knows there is an variable in the session with the previous used file, so the script will then load the previous used file.

Comment: function myClick() {
        $.post('script.php?button=1', {});
    }

    function myClick2() {
        $.post('script.php?button=2', {});
    }

    function myClick3() {
        $.post('script.php?button=3', {});
    }

Comment: But what would I do instead of:

Comment: setInterval(function() {
                $.get(
                    'script.php',
                    {},
                    function (data) {
                        if (data != lastValue) {
                            myFunc();
                            lastValue = data;
                        }
                    }

                );
            },100);

Comment: I don't know how to set a $.get() parameter in my JS code! I could do something like $.get(
                    'script.php?button=1',
                    {},
                    function (data) {
                        if (data != lastValue) {
                            myFunc();
                            lastValue = data;
                        }
                    }

                );, but I want to be checking for all the buttons, not just 1. I can't have 3 $.get()'s though, because that's what was making it not work before.

Comment: @Fjpackard, i've added some little explanation. You can use only `script.php` for the html update ( because then there will be no button clicked right? or am i not understanding it right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44078/discussion-between-fjpackard-and-mathlight)

Comment: @Fjpackard, if you need any more help, contact me at the given email adress. I'm happy to help you out with any (programming) problem...